# unlock HTML files

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap

I've an app which is basically a book, written in HTML deployed with phonegap to Apple Store and Google PlayStore.

I will soon updating my app in the store but I would like to officer "in-app purchase" for some of the sections of the book.

I've gone through several plugins in the market but could not figure out how to unlock the pages. The procedure in my app should be,

1. User taps on section
2. Section prompts a text to request payment
3. User completes payment (either consumable/annual subscription or non-consumable/life time)
4. User able to read rest of the HTML pages in the app.

I really much appreciate your comments/guidance to help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can check your url in the webview WebViewClient.
so if you want to block page then show inapp purchase dialogue else you can show that page

```
  wb_webview = findViewById(R.id.wb_webview);
        wb_webview.setWebViewClient(new web_client());
        WebSettings settings = wb_webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

```
  private class web_client extends WebViewClient {
        private web_client() {
        }

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String str) {
            //check page you want to show
            if(show){
              wb_webview.loadUrl(str);
            }else{
              //inapp purchase dialaug display
           }


            return true;
        }
    }
```

may be it`s work

Comment: Thanks indeed a great comment, Hardik. Thank you!

I am trying to figure this out with JS/HTML only not over Android Studio.